# Discrepancies in adf.test() results

Tags: r, time-series

To Identify whether time series is stationary or explosive I have performed `adf.test` with changing alternative

1) I have used

```
adf.test(Adjpickt,alternative = 's')
```

> Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test
>
> data:  Adjpickt
>   Dickey-Fuller = -3.1245, Lag order = 4, p-value = 0.1139
>   alternative hypothesis: stationary

2)

```
adf.test(Adjpickt,alternative = 'e')
```

> Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test
>
> data:  Adjpickt
>   Dickey-Fuller = -3.1245, Lag order = 4, p-value = 0.8861
>   alternative hypothesis: explosive

In both cases test accepted Null Hypothesis in first case explosive and other Stationary.

I am confusing which one shall I prefer whether its stationary or explosive or any better way to do that ?

Please check below data.

Adjpickt : structure(c(1.12369942196532, 1.10537870472009, 1.22507708119219, 
1.29318854886476, 1.40355805243446, 1.17364203027605, 1.09056244041945, 
1.05433526011561, 1.03183315038419, 1.0945529290853, 1.00098716683119, 
1.04588014981273, 1.08637577916296, 1.13250714966635, 1.22080924855491, 
1.24149286498353, 1.24357656731757, 1.27640671273445, 1.38389513108614, 
1.33036509349955, 1.06482364156339, 1.10057803468208, 0.995609220636663, 
0.943473792394656, 0.943731490621915, 0.875468164794007, 0.814781834372217, 
0.851286939942803, 1.05780346820809, 1.08122941822173, 0.920863309352518, 
0.97137216189536, 0.995318352059925, 1.04719501335708, 1.21353670162059, 
1.10635838150289, 1.2371020856202, 1.31551901336074, 1.41855873642646, 
1.38014981273408, 1.38112199465717, 1.27645376549094, 1.25202312138728, 
1.25686059275521, 1.25077081192189, 1.18953603158934, 1.00187265917603, 
1.07301869991095, 1.10962821734986, 1.10982658959538, 1.25246981339188, 
1.07708119218911, 0.99111549851925, 0.925093632958801, 0.970614425645592, 
1.21544327931363, 1.05664739884393, 1.01536772777168, 1.14182939362795, 
1.12043435340573, 1.04681647940075, 0.976847729296527, 0.917063870352717, 
0.978034682080925, 1.05708013172338, 1.10585817060637, 1.12931885488648, 
1.22659176029963, 1.08815672306322, 1.05815061963775, 1.05549132947977, 
1.01207464324918, 0.996916752312436, 1.06021717670286, 1.06086142322097, 
1.07301869991095, 1.02001906577693, 1.08901734104046, 1.02305159165752, 
0.984583761562179, 0.986179664363278, 0.941947565543071, 1.04452359750668, 
1.19733079122974, 1.14104046242775, 1.0801317233809, 1.10483042137718
), .Tsp = c(1, 87, 1), class = "ts")

Comment: No test ever "accepts the null hypothesis", you just fail to reject the null hypothesis.. When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. But this doesn't seem like a programming question that's right for Stack Overflow. This seems like a question about statistics which belongs on [stats.se].